# TTL Expired packets being lost

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking

I have the following set up:-

Ubuntu 14.04 Linux Server in AWS Private subnet
|
Ubuntu server running LibreSwan IPSEC Gateway
|
Remote IPSEC Gateway
|
Various intermediate hops
|
Target Device

I am pinging a the remote target and then decrementing the TTL so as to obtain per hop statistics.
For hops along the route from the 10 network i get the TTL_Expired packets back to the Linux server in AWS (i can see both IN and OUT packets).
For other hops along the route with a 200.200.200.x or a 192.168.x.x address the packets get back to the IPSEC gateway in AWS (as proven via tcpdump with -P in) but they never leave the gateway (as proven via tcpdump -P out).

I have security associations up and running for all 3 networks.
I have disabled kernel params that may limit or block icmp so it looks like the following:-

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_errors_use_inbound_ifaddr = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_ratelimit = 1000
net.ipv4.icmp_ratemask = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
```

Looking at a raw dump in wireshark and there is no obvious difference in the packets.

iptables on the gateway has INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT set to ACCEPT.

Has anyone experienced anything similar - is there a gotcha I am not aware of.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using ping to gather statistics, you are fooling yourself. Ping is designed for a single purpose, and that is to check network connectivity. ICMP will not perform the same way as, for instance, TCP in your network.

Comment: Understood - this is one of a number of metrics captured.

Comment: What about `net.ipv4.forward = 1`?

Comment: `ubuntu@ip-100-64-0-82:~$ sudo sysctl -a | grep ipv4 | grep forward
    net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
    net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
    net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
    net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
    net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
    net.ipv4.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
    net.ipv4.conf.ip_vti0.forwarding = 1
    net.ipv4.conf.ip_vti0.mc_forwarding = 0
    net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
    net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
    net.ipv4.conf.tun0.forwarding = 1
    net.ipv4.conf.tun0.mc_forwarding = 0
    net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`